# Angular – How to Make Resource Global?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I currently am loading audio track resources to the "Works" page of my website successfully. Here is how my "Works" controller is achieving this:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('appName')
  .controller('WorksCtrl', function ($scope, $http, socket) {
    $scope.works = [];

    $http.get('/api/works').success(function(works) {
      $scope.works = works;
      socket.syncUpdates('work', $scope.works);
    });
  });
```

However, now I need my tracks to be accessed globally across the entire site. Can I achieve this with a factory in my central app.js, and if so, how?

Comment: I would actually use a service as they are singletons so the request would be done only once and you can have access to the same info everywhere you inject that service.

Comment: That sounds great. Can you explain how I go about making a service to do this?

Comment: @LouisCruz my answer is what's in the comment I just used factory instead of service, both are shorthand for defining a provider https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers

Comment: @shaunhusain Thanks for the info. Still trying to wrap my head around Angular!

Comment: @LouisCruz no problem, yeah this is one of the tough parts but once you figure out what's going on it all works really well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
'use strict';

angular.module('appName')
  .controller('WorksCtrl', function ($scope, WorksFactory) {
    $scope.WorksFactory = WorksFactory; //can refer to works in the view from WorksFactory.works
  });
  .factory('WorksFactory', function ($http, socket) {
    var fact = { works: []};

    $http.get('/api/works').success(function(works) {
      angular.copy(works, fact.works);
      socket.syncUpdates('work', fact.works);
    });
    return fact;
  });
```